# Get Duplicates Objects from ArrayList

Tags: java

How can I get duplicates from an ArrayList?

```
public class Order {

    private String portId;
    private String action;
    private String idType;
    private String id;
    private BigDecimal amount;


    public String getPortId() {
        return portId;
    }
    public void setPortId(String portId) {
        this.portId = portId;
    }
    public String getAction() {
        return action;
    }
    public void setAction(String action) {
        this.action = action;
    }
    public String getIdType() {
        return idType;
    }
    public void setIdType(String idType) {
        this.idType = idType;
    }
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public BigDecimal getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }
    public void setAmount(BigDecimal amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }


}
```

My code:

```
List<Order> duplicateList = new ArrayList<Order>();
List<Order> nonDuplicateList = new ArrayList<Order>();

Set<Order> set = new HashSet<Order>();
for (Order order : listContainingAllOrders) {
    if (!set.add(order)) {

        duplicateList.add(order);
    } else {
        nonDuplicateList.add(order);
    }
}
```

I want to achieve duplicateList and nonDuplicateList, where I will combine both the duplicate list and Non duplicate List together
and display on the UI. The duplicate Orders will be Identified by Error Message column.

Comment: You should think about what your functions are doing. Stepping through your program with a debugger can be very helpful. Though I'd probably take the easier route and just print stuff. Either way, understand your flow.

Comment: Does your `Order` class properly implement `hashCode` and `equals`?  If it doesn't, then you'll never have the "add" method returning true unless they are exactly the same object.

Comment: How to override HashCode and equals methods I have 5 variables in Order Object

Comment: @user3810342 Please post your `Order` class.

Comment: @user3810342 Hey! I added my Class. Please let me know if you need any Info. I really appreciate your help in solving this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you, then you could replace this

```
if (!set1.add(order)) {
```

with

```
if (!set1.contains(order)) {
  set1.add(order);
```

**Edit**

You need to Override `equals()` and `hashCode()` in your `Order`. Assuming that Order(s) with the same `id` are equal by definition - one possible way would be,

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
  if (obj instanceof Order) {
    if (id == null) {
      // return ((Order) obj).id == null;
      return false; // probably best to prevent null
    }
    return id.equals(((Order) obj).id);
  }
  return false;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
  return id.hashCode();
}
```

Comment: This is strange. The code above should work as expected unless the repeated elements are the same object references.